# Reset progress bar after form submit using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a progress bar on a form which works fine but I need to reset its value after the file as been upload.

My code:

```
<div class="bar-position">
  <div class="col-md-14 col-md-14 progress-container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using this after the file upload but it does not work:

```
$('.progress').val(0);
```

Where am I going wrong? I have looked at a number of posts but I can't find a solution that will work with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that:

```
$('.progress-bar').attr('style', "width: 0%");
```

Here the snippet:

```js
$('#reset').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.progress-bar').attr('style', "width: 0%");
});
$('#upload').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.progress-bar').attr('style', "width: 100%");
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-position">
  <div class="col-md-14 col-md-14 progress-container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:100%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="upload" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You progress bar uses `width` property to show progress. To reset it use the following:

```
$('.progress-bar').css("width","0%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this by jQuery:

```
$('.progress.active').val(progress); //ENTER PROGRESS BAR VARIABLE HERE
  if ($('.progress.active').val() >= 100) { //IF 100% PROGRESS 
    $('.progress.active').val(0); //VALUE WILL BE RESET 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however its producing the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: progress is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

What i was looking for is to reanimate the process bar after submitting the form, what works for me was to remove the element first then add it back again after setTimeout function. But you can attached it on an event when progress bar value is 100.

```
 setTimeout(()=> {
    $('.progress-bar').remove();   
    $('.progress').prepend(`<div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>`)
  },3000);
```